# Java: Identifying Ints and Non Ints in a string

Tags: java, tokenize

Hello I'm trying to fix a bug in my code. When reading an incoming phrase this code doesn't seems to count integers. It counts the number of non integer words no problem. 
For example if I have the following sentence :
"I love my 4 cats"
It should show that I have 4 Non integer words an 1 integer. But this is not the case with the integer, it seems to identify it as a word
Any ideas?

```
String[] stra = phrase.split(" ");    
         int numInts = 0;    
         int numNonInts = 0;    
         for (String s : stra) {    
             try {    
                 Integer.parseInt(s);    
             }    
             catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {    
                 numNonInts++;    
                 continue;    
             }    
             numInts++;    
         }
```

Comment: This code works just fine on my system; it tokenizes into four words and one non-word.  Are you sure this code is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
     String[] stra = phrase.split("\\W+");    // + for sequences
     int numInts = 0;    
     int numNonInts = 0;    
     for (String s : stra) {    
         try {    
             Integer.parseInt(s);    
             numInts++;    
         }    
         catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {    
             numNonInts++;    
         }    
     }
```

Two spaces would have counted as one word.
Also `\\W` includes all non-word chars.

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than the OP's original code?

Comment: @JB Nizet- The OP's code won't increment `numInts` on each iteration; the `continue` will jump the loop back up to the top rather than continuing after the `catch`.  It's convoluted, but it works (I've verified it on my system)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I missed the continue. I hate continue.

Comment: @templatetypedef done in the answer. I suspected a mistake of interpretation as split(" ") is very strict.

Comment: The original code is basically correct. So he must have tried it with two spaces or such.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Integer.valueOf(s);
```

instead of

```
Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Comment: Why would this help?  How would this address the problem?

Comment: Don't see how this would help considering Integer.valueOf() just calls Integer.parseInt() internally.  If i'm not mistaken the only difference is the return type (int vs Integer)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid unexpected separators (like tabs, double spaces or line break), replace you split by:

```
phrase.split("\\s+");
```

And maybe you got numbers that exceed the limit of `Integer`.

Replace your loop by:

```
for (String s : stra) {
    if(s.matches("\\d+"))
        numInts++;    
    else            
        numNonInts++;    
}
```